# Update json property dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am rendering a table with some values, but the only value that I need to get manually is the cpk because it is a calculation. Hence it is the only value that should change dynamically. To do this I am using a computed property. However, when I draw the table the cpk value does not get rendered in the table.

````
    <v-container>
        <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="processes"
            class="elevation-1"
        >
            <template #[`item.cpk`]="{ item }">
                <v-chip
                    :color="getColor(item.cpk)"
                    dark
                >
                    {{ item.cpk }}
                </v-chip>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import core from "../../api/repositories/core";

export default {
    name: "Dashboard",

    created() {
        this.minuendValues();
        this.subtrahendValues();
        console.log('Data')
    },

    data() {
        return {
            headers: [
                {
                    text: 'Process Name',
                    align: 'left',
                    sortable: false,
                    value: 'name'
                },
                {text: 'Part Number', value: 'partNumber'},
                {text: 'Operation Name', value: 'operationName'},
                {text: 'Data Collection Title', value: 'dataCollectionTitle'},
                {text: 'Cpk', value: 'cpk'}
            ],
            processes: [
                {
                    name: 'EXC RHAD',
                    partNumber: '770404',
                    operationName: 'RHAD Impregnation',
                    dataCollectionTitle: 'Wet Weight',
                    cpk: this.minuendCPK,
                },
                {
                    name: 'EXC RHAD',
                    partNumber: '770404',
                    operationName: 'RHAD Impregnation',
                    dataCollectionTitle: 'Dry Weight',
                    cpk: this.subtrahendCPK,
                },

            ],

            requestData: [],

            // CPK value variables
            minuendCPK: '',
            subtrahendCPK: ''
        }
    },
    computed: {
        minuendCpk() {
            return this.calculateCpk(776, 716, this.calculateDataAverage(this.requestData), this.calculateStandardDeviation(this.requestData));
        },
        subtrahendCpk() {
            return this.calculateCpk(776, 716, this.calculateDataAverage(this.requestData), this.calculateStandardDeviation(this.requestData));
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async minuendValues() {
            try {
                const {data} = await core.getMinuendValues();
                console.log(data);
                this.requestData = data;
                this.minuendCPK = this.minuendCpk;

            } catch (e) {
                console.log("error: ", e);
            }
        },
        async subtrahendValues() {
            try {
                const {data} = await core.getSubtrahendValues();
                console.log(data);
                this.requestData = data;
                this.subtrahendCPK = this.subtrahendCpk;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("error: ", e);
            }
        },

        calculateDataAverage(data) {
            const mean = (data.reduce((acc, obj) => acc + parseInt(obj.DataCollectionValue), 0) /  data.length).toFixed(2);


            return mean;
        },

        calculateStandardDeviation(data) {
            const mean = this.calculateDataAverage(data);

            const variance = data.reduce((acc, obj) => acc + Math.pow(parseInt(obj.DataCollectionValue) - mean, 2), 0) / data.length;

            const stdDev = Math.sqrt(variance).toFixed(2);

            return stdDev;
        },

        // Process capability rules
        calculateCpk(usl, lsl, mean, standardDeviation) {
            let tempX;
            let tempY;
            tempX = (usl - mean) / (3 * standardDeviation);
            tempY = (mean - lsl) / (3 * standardDeviation);

            return Math.min(tempX, tempY).toFixed(2);
        },

        getColor(cpk) {
            if (cpk > 1.33) {
                return 'green';
            }
            else if (cpk >= 1 && cpk <= 1.329) {
                return 'orange';
            }
            else {
                return 'red';
            }
        },

    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style> ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your `processes` data is using `cpk: this.minuendCPK`.  That wil not be reactive, and will just copy the value at the moment it is instantiated.

To fix this, make your `processes` computed, so it will track changes to `cpk: this.minuendCPK`.